# ruby on rails db setup format/ active record retrieval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, many-to-many

My app has *user*, *photo*, and *state* models with the following setup:

> A *state* has many users.
>
> A *user* has many photos.

I have the photos view set up as the homepage (application.root). I am trying to set up a *select* tag to filter the photos w.r.t the selected state.

In View:

```
<%= form_tag photos_path, :method => 'get' do%>
    <%= select("state", "name", State.all.collect(&:name)) %>
    <%= submit_tag "State" %>
<% end %>
```

In Controller:

```
if params[:state]
    statesmen = State.find_by_name(params[:state][:name]).users
    statesmen.each do |person|
        @photos = @photos <<  Photo.where(:user_id => person.id)
    end
end
```

## Questions:

- Is there a better way to collect the photos?
- Currently, the *photos* table only has a `user_id` column. Should I just create a `state_id` column too?
- What's wrong with the current approach?

Comment: Check the edits. Next time please consider making descriptive sentences, formatting code and avoiding HTML tags where you can (especially for single line break). Remember, quality *does* improve the chances of getting prompt attention. Welcome to *stack* **overflow**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your associations are set up as follows:

state.rb

```
has_many :users
```

user.rb

```
belongs_to :state
has_many :photos
```

photo.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Just add to state.rb

```
has_many :photos, :through => :users
```

Then you can do just:

```
@photos = State.find_by_name(params[:state][:name]).photos
```